# Changes made in sabre are not immediately reflecting in API

Tags: sabre

When a change is made in sabre and when we try to capture itinerary details using the PNR. The changes are not instantaneously reflected in the response. It takes 5 to 10 minutes to get changed data in the sabre response.

Answer (score 0):

The modification will only be available once it has been committed; this is done by using the 6 which stands for sign, ER, which stand for end and retrieve.